# How to set org-mode category icon on per file basis?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, icons

***Can you set org-mode category icon on per file basis? If so, then how?***

It is usually set by adding icons to `org-agenda-category-icon-alist` globally, like so:

```el
(setq org-agenda-category-icon-alist '(
    ("computer" ,(list (all-the-icons-material "computer" :height 1.0)) nil nil :ascent center)
))
```

Further, there is an option available to specify the category (but not the icon, which would be really nice) on per file basis, as follows (e.g., in a file called `not_computer.org`)[[1]](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/org/In_002dbuffer-settings.html):

```el
#+CATEGORY: computer
```

Finally, there is a way to specify file local variables, but I do not think that would help (my elisp is not sufficient to solve this)[[2]](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html):

```el
-*- mode: modename; var: value; ... -*-
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to accomplish: category icons in `org-agenda-category-icon-alist` are used when displaying the agenda, so having them defined per file is just not going to work.

Comment: It would work the same way as `#+CATEGORY:`. I assume that works by checking for it when loading the agenda files and using the filename instead if not found.